# Converting XML into Dataframe in R

Tags: r, xml, dataframe

I'm struggling with converting XML into a Dataframe in R
[see XML here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fy7Cp.png)

Thus far, I have managed to get all of the xml attributes into a dataframe, but need the "Q id" information for a few "qualifier_id". Here is the current code:

```
df_list <- lapply(list.filenames, function(f) {
doc <- read_xml(f)

setNames(data.frame(
  xml_attr(xml_find_all(doc, "//Event"), "timestamp"),
  xml_attr(xml_find_all(doc, "//Event"), "id"),
  xml_attr(xml_find_all(doc, "//Event"), "version"),
  xml_attr(xml_find_all(doc, "//Event"), "last_modified"),
  xml_attr(xml_find_all(doc, "//Event"), "y"),
  xml_attr(xml_find_all(doc, "//Event"), "x"),
  xml_attr(xml_find_all(doc, "//Event"), "outcome"),
  xml_attr(xml_find_all(doc, "//Event"), "team_id"),
  xml_attr(xml_find_all(doc, "//Event"), "sec"),
  xml_attr(xml_find_all(doc, "//Event"), "min"),
  xml_attr(xml_find_all(doc, "//Event"), "period_id"),
  xml_attr(xml_find_all(doc, "//Event"), "type_id"),
  xml_attr(xml_find_all(doc, "//Event"), "event_id")

), c("timestamp", "id", "version", "last_modified", "y", "x", "outcome", "team_id", "sec", "min", "period_id", "type_id", "event_id"))
```

})

The dataframe looks like this:
[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZrdE.png)

Ideally, I would have extra columns for a few "qualifier_id". For example, a column called "213" with values from the "value" and NA if not there.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please post your xml as data, not as an image... same goes for your df...

Answer (score 0):

You are already using xml2, so this is pretty easy using the right `xpath`..

```
library(xml2)
```

**sample data**

```
doc <- read_xml("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
                <root>
                <Event id='1'>
                <Q id='' qualifier_id='12'/>
                <Q id='' qualifier_id='123' value='hello'/>
                <Q id='' qualifier_id='1234'/>
                <Q id='' qualifier_id='1' value='goodbye'/>
                </Event>
                <Event id='2'>
                <Q id='' qualifier_id='2'/>
                <Q id='' qualifier_id='1234'/>
                <Q id='' qualifier_id='1' value='goodbye'/>
                </Event>
                </root>")
```

**code**

```
#get list of Event-nodes
Event.nodes <- xml_find_all( doc, "//Event")

#in each node, find the first Q-node with qualifier_id attribute == 123
#from this node, extract the value of attribute 'value' 
#if no Q-node is found, return NA
xml_attr( xml_find_first( Event.nodes, "./Q[@qualifier_id='123']"), "value" )

#[1] "hello" NA
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks very much. I definitely won't upload images in the future.